# How do speakers of languages which can form arbitrary long words deal with long words?

Tags: words, agglutination

Looking at [this long word list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_words) and coming from [this conlang question](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/1491/how-long-do-words-get-in-other-languages-and-how-hard-are-long-words-to-say-or), I am wondering how languages which allow for arbitrarily long words (I don't know for sure, but agglutinative languages, or German, Turkish, Navajo, Inuktitut?) deal with the long words. Are they easy to understand in comparison to breaking things out into separate words? Are there any studies on this? Are they difficult to read (or do your eyes get used to seeing patterns in the words)? What are the pros and cons, for those who are fluent in or understand these sorts of languages at a deeper level than an English-only speaker?

Comment: How do languages which allow for arbitrarily long sentences deal with the long sentences?

Comment: You all are so harsh, I am coming from a good place I tell you.

Comment: I don't mean to be harsh; that's just how I would answer the question. English-speakers have no difficulty understanding long sentences made up of a lot of different units; Inuktitut-speakers similarly have no difficulty understanding long words made up of a lot of different units. The key is recognizing the units and the relationships between them.

Comment: I know from experience that speakers of agglutinative languages like Finnish find it difficult to keep track of very long _derivation chains_ – that is, words that have a single root and then a long chain of affixes that create derived terms and then modify the previous derivation base (like _usefulness_ which is _[use + -ful] + -ness_) – but easier with compounds. For example, if you ask a Finnish speaker what _epäjärjestelmällistyttämättömyydelläänsäkänköhänpä_ means, they’ll likely need to hear or read it several times to understand that it is a surprised, rhetoric way of exclaiming, ->

Comment: -> “What, even with his lack of ability to make everything unsystematic, huh?” (more or less). A compound word of similar length, like _lentokonesuihkuturbiinimoottoriapumekaanikkoaliupseerioppilas_ (‘aircraft jet turbine engine assistant mechanic sub-officer student’) is more easily understood. This does not apply to speakers of polysynthetic languages like Greenlandic, though, where the former is the normal way to construct sentences and the latter (multiple-root compounding) is almost completely unknown.

Answer (score 3):

The only agglutinative language I can speak is Kannada and from my understanding of how native speakers of Kannada deal with agglutination, they do not find it more "difficult" or "easier" as such to read or form "long" words when compared to using a string of disjoint words. Both are used in separate contexts. I am not really sure what it is you are trying to ask. Can you explain with an example? In regards with writing, reading "long" words in Kannada is quite straightforward at least to me, I am not sure how native speakers read them. There are some extreme examples of "long" words I have seen mainly in classical literature and poetry, for example ಮೃಗಗಳಿಗಂಜಿದೊಡೆಂತಯ್ಯ where I suppose the different components would be ಮೃಗ (animal) + ಗಳು (plural marker) + ಇಗೆ (dative marker) + ಅಂಜು (fear) + ದೊಡೆ + ಎಂತ (how) + ಅಯ್ಯ [I am unable to find exact gloss for the last three such that it would make sense]. This is a single word that roughly translates to "How pitiful it would be to fear animals." In regular modern speech you would not normally hear such extreme cases of joining too many components together and it would be easier to say something like "ಮೃಗಗಳಿಗೆ ಅಂಜಿದೊಡೆ ಎಂತಯ್ಯ?" (this still sounds classical and is not like how the modern spoken language is, but it is a much simpler way of saying it). But there are examples of very commonly used words formed by agglutination, and people do not have any difficulty in producing or reading these words.